# Position Measurement of Quantum Harmonic Oscillator, to a Position Eigenstate

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, measurement-problem

I read that if one takes a quantum harmonic oscillator system, not externally driven, and performs a position measurement (measurement in position basis) that reduces the oscillator to an eigenstate of position (or, I suppose, to very "close" to that, so that it is localized between $x + \epsilon$ and $x - \epsilon$ for arbitrarily small $\epsilon$), the system is no longer an oscillator.

Does anybody know why that would be?

Comment: Why would it not be an oscillator? The measurement simply puts it into a mix of excited states, but that doesn't change the Hamiltonian.

Comment: See p 70 Arno Bohm (not David Bohm) "Quantum Mechanics"  It wasn't clear to me, either, so I am asking      https://books.google.com/books?id=FDHUBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA70&lpg=PA70&dq=%22according+to+10.17+after+a+measurement%22+bohm&source=bl&ots=NMuND8EBVO&sig=ii4LS8V3mnIqVwooyU1My0LRg-I&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwipwM_JwbXLAhUJVD4KHdroDDkQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22according%20to%2010.17%20after%20a%20measurement%22%20bohm&f=false

Comment: may be  the following  is happening.....The quantum Zeno effect (also known as the Turing paradox) is a situation in which an unstable particle, if observed continuously, will never decay. One can "freeze" the evolution of the system by measuring it frequently enough in its known initial state.....Ref.>https://espace.library.uq.edu.au/view/UQ:157843/n03chapter2.pdf<

Comment: @ drvrm: Could be. Maybe also the expectation value for its energy approaches infinity, as the localization interval continues to shrink, or the complete uncertainty in momentum is incompatible with energy eigenstates. Not really sure, but was surprised to read it. Never saw that anywhere else.

Comment: After reading the passage I would suggest to repurpose the book as a door stop... that doesn't make any sense, whatsoever.

Comment: @ CuriousOne Could you please join me in http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36799/harmonic-oscillator-position-eigenstate ?

Comment: Maybe this explains it: If the probability density of the measuring device is prepared in a Gaussian state, with an $extremely$ small standard deviation (width), such that the Gaussian is effectively 0, except in a very small interval, then the probability density of the combined ensemble of measuring device and system is the product of their probability densities and is essentially 0, except in that small interval. There is room for the expectation value of the system's position to oscillate between.